# Unable to display calendar events in fullcalendar dashboard using jquery and java

Tags: java, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I am unable display events(that are present in my database) on the fullcalendar dashboard. I created a JSON file and that contains my JSON array of events which I am getting them at runtime. I am giving the url of the events in jquery as

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },

    events: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/calendarFetch',
```

My json file that is dynamically generated has output of this format

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "start": "2015-11-09 01:30:00",
            "end": "2015-11-09 02:30:00",
            "title": "Meeting with Professor"
        },
        {
            "start": "2015-11-09 01:30:00",
            "end": "2015-11-09 02:30:00",
            "title": "Meeting with Professor"
        },
        {
            "start": "2015-11-09 01:30:00",
            "end": "2015-11-09 02:30:00",
            "title": "Meeting with Professor"
        },
        {
            "start": "2015-11-09 01:30:00",
            "end": "2015-11-09 02:30:00",
            "title": "Meeting with Professor"
        },
        {
            "start": "2015-11-09 01:30:00",
            "end": "2015-11-09 02:30:00",
            "title": "Meeting with Professor"
        },
        {
            "start": "2015-11-09 01:30:00",
            "end": "2015-11-09 02:30:00",
            "title": "Meeting with Professor"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The events feed output should be sending json for an array of objects, looking like this

```
[
        {
            "start": "2015-11-09 01:30:00",
            "end": "2015-11-09 02:30:00",
            "title": "Meeting with Professor"
        },
        {
            "start": "2015-11-09 01:30:00",
            "end": "2015-11-09 02:30:00",
            "title": "Meeting with Professor"
        }
]
```

Remove the enclosing `{ "events": ... }` from your output and it should work

Comment: It didn't work out. My json file has output of this format now
[{"start":"2015-11-09 01:30:00","end":"2015-11-09 02:30:00","title":"Meeting with Professor"},....]

Comment: ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/calendarFetch It may be expanding to an incorrect path? When you view the page source, if you copy the events url into the browser and go there do you see event json?